# Is there a way to reset or repair (keyboard) input methods in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

I am a frequent user of the Chinese (PRC) input in Windows 10. I am on version 1703. It is the first input method counting from the bottom:

My Region & language settings:
              [image: A picture of my Region & language settings]
                [[Click for full-size image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0HTN.png)

Recently the candidate box of this input method has consistently failed to open. An explanation in pictures:

In the Google search bar, I type `yuexiameiren`, as follows:
[image: What happens when I type "yuexiameiren"]

The first two automatically chosen characters are correct, but not the last two. So I choose "2" in the candidate box.

Here's what happens:
the candidate box fails to appear for the "meiren" part:
[image: The candidate box fails to appear for the "meiren" part]

The dotted line shows that the input method is still waiting for me to choose from the candidate box, except that the candidate box does not appear. If I press <kbd>space</kbd>, the same two previously chosen (incorrect) characters appear. If I press <kbd>Return</kbd>, the dotted line disappears along with the apostrophe, leaving the *pinyin* as-is. Pressing *down/up arrow*, *page down/up* or *-/+* has no effect.

This is occurring with such frequency that typing seven consecutive characters requires five or six different input instances, because if I was to correct the second character, the candidate box disappears for the remainder of my input, forcing me to erase whatever remains and restart from the third character. To get around this, I have been typing character by character, a very time-consuming process.

I have tried the built-in "Restore defaults" button to no avail. Running the usual `sfc` or `DISM` checks return no errors.

The Japanese input method, which I also use frequently, does not suffer from this problem.

Is there a way to reset or repair the Chinese (PRC) input method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to the latest Windows 10 version.

On my 1709 machine, Microsoft Pinyin is healthy, when I type yuexiameiren, it shows the content below, same as you.
[image]

When I choose 2, 美人 candidate appears automatically, even don't need to hit space
[image]

Try to update system to fix input issue.

On the other hand, since you are familiar with Chinese, I suggest to use Sogou Pinyin IME or Google Pinyin IME, which are widely used by Chinese, as me